# Class not found when I use namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I'm new with namespaces and I'm making tests but when I run app.php I get the next error:

> Fatal error: Class 'ProtocoloWT\models\status' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wt.uptkd\protocoloWt\app.php

.

**app.php**

```
use Neomerx\JsonApi\Encoder\Encoder;
use Neomerx\JsonApi\Encoder\EncoderOptions;
use ProtocoloWT\models\status;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$status = status::instance(http_response_code(204));

$encoder = Encoder::instance([
    '\status' => '\statusEsquema',
], new EncoderOptions(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, 'http://example.com/api/v1'));

echo $encoder->encodeData($status);
```

**status.php**

```
namespace ProtocoloWT\models;

class status
{
    public static function instance ($status)
    {
        $estado = new status();

        $estado->status = $status;

        return $estado;
    }
}
```

**composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "neomerx/json-api",
  "description": "Framework agnostic JSON API (jsonapi.org) implementation",
  "keywords": [
    "jsonapi.org",
    "json-api",
    "jsonapi",
    "neomerx",
    "json",
    "api"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/neomerx/json-api",
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/neomerx/json-api/issues"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "neomerx",
      "email": "info@neomerx.com"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "psr/http-message": "^1.0",
    "psr/log": "^1.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.6 || ^5.0 || ^6.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "~0.9.4",
    "scrutinizer/ocular": "^1.3",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.5",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.18",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.6"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Neomerx\\JsonApi\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Neomerx\\Tests\\JsonApi\\": "tests/",
      "Neomerx\\Samples\\JsonApi\\": "sample/"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": ["@test-unit", "@test-cs", "@test-md"],
    "test-unit": "./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --coverage-text",
    "test-unit-with-coverage": "phpdbg -qrr ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text",
    "test-cs": "./vendor/bin/phpcs -p -s --standard=PSR2 ./src ./tests",
    "test-md": "./vendor/bin/phpmd ./src text codesize,controversial,cleancode,design,unusedcode,naming",

    "perf-php": "docker-compose run --rm cli_php php /app/sample/sample.php -t=10000",
    "perf-hhvm": "docker-compose run --rm cli_hhvm hhvm /app/sample/sample.php -t=10000"
  }
}
```

File app.php is in a directory called `protocoloWT/` and status.php is in `protocoloWT/models`.

I installed a framework with composer and I can use those namespaces (Neomerx\JsonApi), but I can't create my own namespaces in my files because I get that error. What could be the issue?

PS: Sorry for my english, I have tried to explain it the best I can

Comment: Could you also post your composer.json

Comment: Done!. But I haven't problems with framework namespaces, I have problems when I use my own namespaces in files that I create.

Comment: If you want to use Composer's autoload functionality, you have to tell Composer about your classes and files.

Comment: Or just manually `require` your source files.

Comment: i tried to use require but it does not work either (I can post the error if it's necessary). But, would it be necessary to use autoload to use namespaces in my own files?